# Python Sklearn Pipelines with GridSearchCV

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, pipeline

I'm playing around with `GridSearchCV` and `Pipeline` in sklearn.  I'm finding inconsistencies, and I'm wondering if I'm just misunderstanding something.

The following two code blocks yield very different predicted `y_pred` results, and I was hoping someone could clarify why.

**Code block 1:**

```
rfr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 1, n_jobs = -1, random_state = 2016, verbose = 1)
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1), stop_words='english')
tsvd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=10, random_state = 2016)
clf = pipeline.Pipeline([
        ('union', FeatureUnion(
                    transformer_list = [
                        ('cst',  cust_regression_vals()),  
                        ('txt1', pipeline.Pipeline([('s1', cust_txt_col(key='search_term')), ('tfidf1', tfidf), ('tsvd1', tsvd)]))
                        ],
                    transformer_weights = {
                        'cst': 1.0,
                        'txt1': 0.5
                        },
                )), 
        ('rfr', rfr)]) # <-- this part is removed in CodeBlock2
param_grid = {'rfr__max_features': [10], 'rfr__max_depth': [20]}
model = grid_search.GridSearchCV(estimator = clf, param_grid = param_grid, cv = 2, verbose = 20, scoring=RMSE) 
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_orig = model.predict(X_test)
```

**Code block 2**:

```
rfr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 1, n_jobs = -1, random_state = 2016, verbose = 1)
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1), stop_words='english')
tsvd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=10, random_state = 2016)
clf = pipeline.Pipeline([
        ('union', FeatureUnion(
                    transformer_list = [
                        ('cst',  cust_regression_vals()),  
                        ('txt1', pipeline.Pipeline([('s1', cust_txt_col(key='search_term')), ('tfidf1', tfidf), ('tsvd1', tsvd)]))
                        ],
                    transformer_weights = {
                        'cst': 1.0,
                        'txt1': 0.5
                        },
                ))
    ])

X_train_trans = clf.fit_transform(X_train,y_train)
X_test_trans = clf.transform(X_test)

param_grid = {'max_features': [10], 'max_depth': [20]}
model = grid_search.GridSearchCV(estimator = rfr, param_grid = param_grid, cv = 2, verbose = 20, scoring=RMSE)
model.fit(X_train_trans, y_train)
y_pred_mod = model.predict(X_test_trans)
```

In the first code block, my RandomForestRegressor classifier is built into the pipeline, whereas in the second code block I abstracted it out.  Any ideas why `y_pred_orig` is vastly different from `y_pred_mod`, when, in my opinion, I'm tracing the same steps the `pipeline` would trace?

**EDIT**: For what it's worth, code block 1 yields a much lower test RMSE, whereas code block 2 yields a much lower train RMSE.  These results confuse me, as I thought both code blocks should yield identical results given that I'm using the same `random_state`.

Comment: Try setting `random_state=2016` in `GridSearchCV`; the default value of `random_state=None` may be overriding the values you've set earlier.

Comment: @maxymoo: I've narrowed down the issue to a difference in the `tfidf` implemention of `fit_transform` vs `fit().transform()` which are supposed to be identical.  In any case, `GridSearchCV` doesn't implement `random_state` (see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html)

Comment: Ah very interesting ... if you've found a bug will you raise it with the scikit-learn team?

Comment: @maxymoo: yeah I will, once I understand exactly what's happening...